# Creating a simple webserver using sockets

Tags: html, c, sockets

I have the following code for server in C. The web browser will serve as the client. So far, what I know is I need to run the executable file from the terminal and open a web browser and type: `localhost:54321` . 54321 is port number where we need to run the web server. The next thing we need to do is parse the http request received from the web browser and obtain the name of the object requested.

I know how to parse but `I don't know how to receive the object`. Should I use `form` inputs to get the name of the object?

Thanks in Advance! Just a newbie in socket programming and I am only able to create sockets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int listenfd,connfd;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
  socklen_t len = sizeof(cliaddr);
  char cli_ip[32];
  char mesg[1024];

  listenfd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(54321);
  if ( bind( listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) ) < 0 ){
      perror(NULL);
      exit(-1);
  }

  //not present in udp server
  listen(listenfd,2);

  while(1){
      //not present in udp server
    connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET,(struct in_addr *) &cliaddr.sin_addr, cli_ip, sizeof(cli_ip) );
    printf("Client %s connected. \n",cli_ip);     
    while(1){
      memset(mesg,0,sizeof(mesg));
      if( recvfrom(connfd,mesg,sizeof(mesg),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len) > 0 ){
            printf("From %s port %d: %s",cli_ip,ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port),mesg);
      }
      else {
        printf("Client %s disconnected. \n",cli_ip);      
        break;
      }
    }
    close(connfd);
  }
  close(listenfd);
  return 0;
}
```

EDITED: This is the exact specifications given:

```
Parse the HTTP request (using strtok) received from the web browser and obtain the name of the object requested. For example, index.html will be sent in the response:
GET /index.html HTML/1.1
Host: localhost:54321
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Comment: Could you explain yourself more?  In particular, you say "The next thing we need to do is parse the http request received from the web browser and obtain the name of the object requested. I know how to parse but I don't know how to receive the object."  If the web browser is requesting an object, why would it be providing said object for you to receive?

Comment: @CortAmmon I edited the question above with the exact specifications given. We need to make a simple webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a training exercise?

You need to keep reading from the socket and parsing as you go, until you determine you have read the entire header.  Then you need to parse it (if you haven't already done so), and send a response.

So, you can't have just one recvfrom(), you need to loop.

It also won't (efficiently) handle multiple browsers until you explicitly support it, via poll/select and/or threads and/or forked processes.